# Передать скрипту файл

Tags: curl, php

Как с можно отправить фал с одного сервера на другой?

Например, на локальном сервер (денвер) движок сайта создает сихронизационный файл (в основном SQL запросы) в виде XML. На внешнем сервер, находится скрипт, который получает этот файл и исполняет команды из файла. Все действия должны проходить на локальном сервере.

Comment: Внешний сервер должен возвращать результат? Если да, то кому? Кому нужен результат -- тот и работает. Поскольку промежуточный сервер -- локальный, то, подозреваю, что Вы там -- хозяин, и с привилегиями проблем не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Простейший пример:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://somedomain/filepost.php'; // url для загрузки
    $file = 'c:\\fail_dlja_uploda.txt'; // выгружаемый файл

    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');

    if ($curl = curl_init()) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file)); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        echo $out;
        curl_close($curl);
    }

    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Возможно, придется строку:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
```

заменить на:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

или вообще их убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Такое вполне осуществимо `ajax'ом`. только получится передавать надо переменные, тогда на внешнем сервере не надо будет работать с файлом, парсить его. Если просто переменные передавать - так будет быстрее. и осуществимее.